# Can't build PortAudio for i386 to make it play nice with NI's DAQmxBase

Tags: c++, c, macos, portaudio, nidaqmx

I'm trying to write a little C/C++ program that both acquires data from an NI USB DAQ and plays audio with PortAudio. The problem is, it appears that the NI DAQ library for Mac/Linux, DAQmxBase, has to be built under i386, and I just can't get PortAudio to build for i386.

I have tried setting CFLAGS and LDFLAGS to `-arch=i386` before running `./configure --disable-mac-universal && make && make install`, but the NI DAQmxBase example code still won't build when I add calls to PortAudio to it:

```
gcc -I../../includes -g -O2 -arch i386 acAnalogTest.c -framework nidaqmxbase -framework nidaqmxbaselv -o acAnalogTest  
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
      "_Pa_Initialize", referenced from:
          _main in ccf1t0bz.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [acAnalogTest] Error 1
```

The NI DAQmxBase Makefile looks like this:

```
nilibs=-framework nidaqmxbase -framework nidaqmxbaselv                                                              
includes=-I../../includes
flags= -g -O2 -arch i386
cc=gcc

ao_examples = acAnalogTest acquireNScans
......
all : $(ao_examples)

% : %.c 
>---$(cc) $(includes) $(flags) $< $(nilibs) -o $@

clean :
>---rm -f $(ao_examples)
```

Changing the -arch flag in the DAQmxBase Makefile doesn't work:

```
gcc -I../../includes -g -O2 -arch x86_64 acAnalogTest.c -framework nidaqmxbase -framework nidaqmxbaselv -o acAnalogTest
In file included from acAnalogTest.c:1:
../../includes/NIDAQmxBase.h:104: warning: division by zero
../../includes/NIDAQmxBase.h:104: error: enumerator value for ‘assert_line_104’ is not an integer constant
../../includes/NIDAQmxBase.h:105: warning: division by zero
../../includes/NIDAQmxBase.h:105: error: enumerator value for ‘assert_line_105’ is not an integer constant
make: *** [acAnalogTest] Error 1
```

I assume this is because DAQmxBase is written with i386 data types in mind. The lines the above error references from NIDAQmxBase.h are:

```
NIStaticAssert(sizeof(long) == 4, "Error: This platform is unsupported because long is not 4 bytes.");              
NIStaticAssert(sizeof(int) == sizeof(long), "Error: This platform is unsupported because int is not the same size as long.");
```

I can build some of the normal PortAudio examples on their own just fine, but I want to put PortAudio and DAQmxBase in the same program together and have them get along. There must be a way to build PortAudio so that it works with DAQmxBase, no?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DAQmx Base versions 14.0 and 15.0 support 64-bit applications, so you should now be able to upgrade the driver and try again.

[DAQmx Base 15.0 for Mac](http://www.ni.com/download/ni-daqmx-base-15.0/5648/en/)